# Unable to install ICEfaces plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, icefaces-3

I am unable to install ICEFaces 3 plugin for eclipse .
I am following below method to install plugin

Help--> Install New Software --> Add --> Archive then browsing the zip file from the local machine. I am getting error "No new software site found at jar:file:---"

Below is the error screenshot 
[image]
Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in Advance

Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You downloaded ICEfaces itself, not the Eclipse plugin. You can find the right download at the [3.x page](http://www.icesoft.org/java/downloads/icefaces-3.x-downloads.jsf) only.